# Install Python 3 alongside python 2.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python3

I have Python2.7 and many libraries that I use to run most of my code. However, I'd like to install python3 alongside it so that I can occasionally use it to test out some new code that I have recently obtained.

How can I install this to avoid causing any issues for the Python2.7 and the installed libraries?

Comment: Python3 is typically installed by default, execute it in a terminal by running `python3` instead of `python`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Hugo stated in the comment above, python3 should already be installed and you can run it by using `python3` in the terminal as he mentioned.

*Setting up virtual Environments:*
You can also setup virtual python environments using pip. Install pip with the following command.

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

(to install pip3 for python3, use this command `sudo apt install python3-pip`)
Now that you have pip installed you can refer to the instructions at this [link](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/) to learn how to setup these virtual environments for testing various python versions and packages

*Switching between python versions using update-alternatives*:
If setting up virtual environments is not what you want to do, then you can also use `update-alternatives` to switch between python version. Run these two commands first, but make sure the python versions match what you have on your computer

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

You may then run `update-alternatives` with the `--config` option so that you may select which version you want to choose to be the default

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Use the interactive menu to select which version you would like to use as the default. In order to check if your changes have worked you can use `python --version`