# Python 3.7.4 isn't being used

Tags: 18.04, python, python3

I'm trying to install BEE2, and the only problem I'm running into is that it's using Python 2.7.15+, but needs Python 3.6+. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.03.

I run `python -v`, and it tells me that 2.7.15 is the latest version.
`python3 -v` tells me I have Python 3.7.4 installed though. While running apt install, I get the same results. Both are at the latest version.

Do I need to force `pyinstaller` to use Python 3?

Comment: provide more details like OS flavor and version

Comment: Done. Sound good? @NuthanKumar

Comment: So, `python` will never be Python 3. Any app that requires python3 should have `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or similar at the top of the script, or you should run it with `python3 app`. I don't know how you're installing BEE2, but it probably needs to be done so with whatever script uses python3 instead of 2.

Comment: I'm going by the install directions on the repository in the README.

https://github.com/BEEmod/BEE2.4

Comment: You can use ``update-alternatives`` to set the default python version. I have provided instructions on how to do that in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken my own answer from a similar question found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142984/684030)

Switching between python versions using update-alternatives:

If setting up virtual environments is not what you want to do, then you can also use update-alternatives to switch between python version. Run these two commands first, but make sure the python versions match what you have on your computer

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1`
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2`

You may then run update-alternatives with the --config option so that you may select which version you want to choose to be the default

`$ sudo update-alternatives --config python`

Use the interactive menu to select which version you would like to use as the default. In order to check if your changes have worked you can use `python --version`

**adding from comments**: you may have to install python-pip3 if pip no longer works after changing the default python version. install it by running `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: PyInstaller isn't working anymore, and PIP isn't recognized.

Comment: Should I reboot?

Comment: You may have to install pip3 ``sudo apt-get install python3-pip``. After Doing that you can try your installations again. On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946882/11705680) they recommend trying ``python -m pip install *package*`` but if that's not applicable for pyinstaller then I apologize

Comment: That was the problem. Now, I've gotten further and am now stuck with a BEEMod issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is it `python3-pip` or `python-pip3`?

Comment: ``python3-pip``. Thank you for clarifying @CStafford-14